# ClojureDart: Class ... has no instance method 'call'

Tags: flutter, dart, clojure

I have encountered this error.
I have a Size object, and I want to get its height and width. In my clojureDart code, I did:

```clj
(.height size)
```

which gave in Dart:

```dart
(size.height() as double)
```

How can I access this property, which I know isn't a function/method ?

Btw I had those warnings:

```
Stern warning: can't resolve member height on target type dynamic of library dart:core at line: 25, column: 42, file: ifs/main.cljd
Stern warning: can't resolve member width on target type dynamic of library dart:core at line: 25, column: 57, file: ifs/main.cljd
```

Comment: I don't really know clojure but `height` on the `Size` object is a getter method in dart. The closest equivalent in java would be probably be an instance field. The clojure website says you use `(.-instanceField instance)` for member access on an instance field in java (https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_member_access). I would try with the instance field syntax `(.-height size)`.

Comment: @mmcdon20 Actually, the (.height size) works but I had to precise that the type was a `m/Size` so it can understand what kind of attribute (a property) we are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have specify what type my variable size was.
Like this :

```clj
(defn transform [pic n ^m/Size size]
  ...
  (.height size))
```

No warnings nor error!